# R uploading data frame to hadoop

Tags: r, hadoop, hive

I currently have an ODBC connection with hadoop on my R. However, I would like to upload my R data frame to hadoop.

How would I do this? Would it be done through RODBC?

Comment: You could use `dbWriteTable` or `dbSendUpdate` but it would be slow (dbWriteTable) when the number of rows increases.  I generally, do in 2 step process i.e. to write in hive and then create table (which is very fast)

Comment: SparkR could be a good alternative